# The launch.json can't debug cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have set launch.json file and tasks.file in .vscode file.
And both JSON files can perfectly work in my old PC.

However, the launch.json can't succeed to debug the CPP file after I copy both JSON files into the new PC, the path of `MinGW64` is same as that in old PC.

I can't find any effective solution that makes me upset.

The followings are my files containing launch.json, tasks.json and cpp file:

```
// cpp file
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

```
// launch.file
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

After debugging, The result is always running, no ending:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqpTv.png)

Comment: can you use gdb from command line ? try running
    gdb fileBasenameNoExtension.exe

Comment: And have you added mingw bin directory to your path ?

Comment: @joker007, I have added MinGW64 as an environment variable in system path, which is written as a path: C:\mingw64\bin

Comment: @joker007: I have tested  fileBasenameNoExtension.exe using gdb in command line. After I enter the command: gdb -q hello, the screen displays the instruction as : Reading symbols from hello...done, which means succeessful test.